# Query INNER JOIN aplicar bind parametro

Tags: php, sql

Query original:

```
SELECT quantity.order_id, quantity.ISBN, quantity.quantity,orders.customer_id, orders.created, orders.status FROM orders INNER JOIN quantity ON orders.order_id=quantity.order_id"
```

Query com bind parameter:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT quantity.order_id, quantity.ISBN, quantity.quantity,orders.customer_id, orders.created, orders.status FROM orders INNER JOIN quantity ON orders.order_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$quantity.order_id);
$quantity.order_id = $_POST['quantity.order_id'];//linha 6
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->get_result();
```

Com o bind parameter estou tendo o seguinte erro:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' on line 6

Comment: O nome do parâmetro que você recebe no POST parece estar errado!

Comment: O nome da variável já está errado. Não é permitido ter `.`.

Comment: como sugere que eu faça? desculpe sou nova em PHP

Comment: Use underline no lugar de ponto para nomear variáveis!

Comment: o quantity.order_id é para ir buscar informação a base de dadosé para ir buscar o id da order da tabela quantity!!

Comment: veja a resposta que coloquei, você não coloca uma coluna da tabela quantity na clausula ON do JOIN, veja se a forma que eu coloquei funciona pra você

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT quantity.order_id, quantity.ISBN, quantity.quantity,orders.customer_id, orders.created, orders.status FROM orders INNER JOIN quantity ON orders.order_id=quantity.order_id and quantity.order_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$quantity.order_id);
$quantity.order_id = $_POST['quantity.order_id'];//linha 6
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->get_result();
```

OU:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare ("SELECT quantity.order_id, quantity.ISBN, quantity.quantity,orders.customer_id, orders.created, orders.status FROM orders INNER JOIN quantity ON orders.order_id=quantity.order_id Where quantity.order_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$quantity.order_id);
$quantity.order_id = $_POST['quantity.order_id'];//linha 6
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->get_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT quantity.order_id, quantity.ISBN, quantity.quantity,orders.customer_id, orders.created, orders.status FROM orders INNER JOIN quantity ON (orders.order_id=quantity.order_id) WHERE quantity.order_id=:id");

$stmt->bind_param(":id",$_POST['quantity.order_id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);

if($stmt->execute())
{
    if($stmt->rowCount() < 1)
        echo "Nenhum resultado encontado.";
    else
        $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
}
else
    echo "erro";
```

Essa variável **$_POST['quantity.order_id']** está correta? Ela vem de algum formulário?

Experimente mudar para um nome sem pontuação, por exemplo:

$_POST['quantity_order_id'].

no HTML deve ficar:

`<input name="quantity_order_id" />`